# SQL Repeat joins different conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2016

I have two tables. The first table Table0 stores a code for each item and that item's name. The second table Table1 stores a 'father' item code and then a number of 'child' item codes for each father.

```
Table0                                 Table1
itemCode | itemName                    fatherCode | childCode | childNum
10101    | Item 1                      10101      | 20101     |  1
20101    | Sub-item 1                  10101      | 20102     |  2
20102    | Sub-item 2
```

The purpose of the children is to show what constituent items are required to make up one of the father. Table0 also stores the codes and names of each of the children items.

I'd like to show the code and name of the father, and then also the code and name of each child next to the father.

What I'm after is something like this:

```
fatherCode | itemName | childCode | itemName2  | childNum
10101      | Item 1   | 20101     | Sub-item 1 | 1
10101      | Item 1   | 20102     | Sub-item 2 | 2
```

I guessed that it would be a simple case of just repeating the joins but with different conditions, but the itemName2 column is just repeating what is in the first itemName.

What I have tried and which didn't work:

```
SELECT
T0.ItemCode,
T0.ItemName,
T1.Code,
T2.ItemName,
T1.Quantity,
T1.ChildNum

FROM Table0 T0
LEFT JOIN Table1 T1 ON T1.Father = T0.ItemCode
INNER JOIN Table0 T2 ON T2.ItemName = T0.ItemName
LEFT JOIN Table1 T3 ON T3.Code = T2.ItemCode

WHERE T1.ChildNum IS NOT NULL

ORDER BY T1.ItemCode
```

Comment: t1 left join t0 left join t0

Comment: Is there a limit to the number of levels?  (can a item have a sub item which has sub items which has sub items which has...)  if so, you'll need to use a recursive CTE to "Loop" or a For Xml Path statement to traverse the hierarchy.  If this is possible then What you're after is the results of a hierarchical query.

Comment: Since you asked for SQL-Server. I guess you want to try a recursive approach. Like Common-Table-Expression (CTE): http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31010/Recursion-in-SQL-using-CTE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need any left joins here.  I think it's just that you need to build the query around `table1` rather than `table0`.

```
select t.fatherCode, f.itemName, t.childCode, c.itemName as itemName2, t.childNum
  from Table1 t
  join Table0 f
    on f.itemCode = t.fatherCode
  join Table0 c
    on c.itemCode = t.childCode
```